# Xpath - Target text inside a span

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to be able to target the text inside the span to use it as input paramater in python. I have been struggling for hours with the Xpath.

```
<ul class="program">
  <li class="list"...
    <a class="listing_link" href="">
      <span class="title text-ellipses">TEXT TO SELECT</span>
```

Here is the most simple I came up with.

```
//ul/li/a/span//text()
```

But it doesn't work.
I also tried stuff like:

```
string(//ul/li/a/span[contains(text(), 'TEXT TO SELECT')])
```

But nothing either.

Note that the snippet is part of a much larger tree. The idea is to target the text inside all occurences of:

```
//ul/li/a/span.
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: https://www.ziggogo.tv/nl/tv-gids.html

Comment: Your xpath works for the fragment you posted. Can you be more specific that "doesn't work"? And can you post a minimal valid xml document mocking out the stuff you want to find? You refer us to some ginormous html page that doesn't seem to correlate with your xml at first glance. Can you narrow this down?

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is use the class name to select the right element and then get the test inside that element. Try this:

```
page.select('//*[@class="title text-ellipses"]/text()').extract()
```

Here, "page" is the html page parsed using "html" method in "lxml" module. Please take a look at my script at [Github](https://github.com/manojps/yelp_utep_2017_team5/blob/master/user_location/user_location_crawler_v2.py) for an example.